# How to read and plot multiple TIFF files in Colaboratory?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, image, for-loop

I'm new in python and I would like to know how I can read and plot **MULTIPLE TIFF files in Colaboratory with (maybe) a for loop**.

Here is what I did for a **single** TIFF image:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive = "/content/drive/MyDrive/exercise"

dataset = gdal.Open(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/exercise/image_20180127.tif')

print(dataset.RasterCount)

band1 = dataset.GetRasterBand(1) #Red Channel

band2 = dataset.GetRasterBand(2) #Green Channel

band2 = dataset.GetRasterBand(3) #Blue Channel

#Read the band as Numpy arrays

b1 = band1.ReadAsArray()

b2 = band1.ReadAsArray()

b3 = band1.ReadAsArray()

#Plot the arrays using imshow()

img = np.dstack((b1,b2,b3))

f=plt.figure()


plt.show()
```

I would like to perform the same actions for **multiple** TIFFs (I have 39) with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try automizing your method by creating two functions: one to open the image and obtain necessary info, and a second to plot. For example,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive = "/content/drive/MyDrive/exercise/"

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal

def loadTiff(in_image, init=None, size_img=None):
    src = gdal.Open(in_image)
    nbands = src.RasterCount
    in_band = src.GetRasterBand(1)  # load one band for size reference
    if init is None:
        xinit,yinit = (0, 0)
    else:
        xinit,yinit = init
    if size_img is None:
        block_xsize, block_ysize = (in_band.XSize, in_band.YSize)
    else:
        block_xsize, block_ysize = size_img

    # read the (multiband) file into an array
    image = src.ReadAsArray(xinit, yinit, block_xsize, block_ysize)
    # reshape from bandsxheightxwidth to wxhxb
    image = np.moveaxis(image, 0, -1)
    return image, block_ysize, block_xsize, nbands

def RGBplot(image, bindex):  # band index should be in order of r,g,b
  #assumes shape is as obtained above
  img = np.dstack((image[:,:,index[0]]/np.percentile(image[:,:,index[0]],95),
                  image[:,:,index[1]]/np.percentile(image[:,:,index[1]],95),
                  image[:,:,index[2]]/np.percentile(image[:,:,index[2]],95)))
  img = np.clip(img, 0, 1)
  f = plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(np.array(img))
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()
```

Then create the loop to go through your images. For example,

```
# how you access the folder will depend on your colab setup, naming system, etc
for image in os.listdir(drive):
  if image.endswith('.tif'):
    [img, xsize, ysize, nbands] = loadTiff(os.path.join(drive,image))
    RGBplot(img, [3,2,1])
```

I can't say if this is the most efficient or effective method but it's worked for me.